# PiVPN on Mobile Device - Wifi Drops and the Phone Reverts to 4G

Tags: wifi, connection, vpn

I recently installed PiVPN.  Although it works, I have noticed that after about 20-30 seconds of 'screen off' time, the phone's connection will drop from wifi to 4G.  This only happens when I am using the VPN.

I have noticed the following log in the PiVPN server when the connection drops:

```
Apr 20 13:22:57 pivpn ovpn-server[9431]: yyy/xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx SIGTERM[soft,remote-exit] received, client-instance exiting
```

Curiously, and for what its worth, the OpenVPN client (iOS) does show a long connection duration which does seem to contradict what I am seeing.

I have tried playing with the `keepalive` setting in `server.conf` changing it from the default `1800 3600` to `10 60`, but it has not made any difference.

Any suggestions? Thoughts?

Comment: Found this post from 2016 detailing what seems to be what I am experiencing.  It surprises me that there has been no progress since then...

https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=20820

Comment: `piVPN` is simply a configuration tool for openVPN, meaning this question is really about openVPN and/or iOS.  The most appropriate places to ask questions about that on the Stack Exchange network are probably [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (~1400 questions tagged `openvpn`), [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) (~600 `openvpn` questions), [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) (~2500 such questions), and/or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (the Apple oriented exchange).